# How does one set multiple cache-control directives in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cache-control

I have to have several certain cache-control directives set on an ASP.NET page in order to pass a Hailstorm security scan. For example, it wants me to have

```
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
```

in addition to

```
Cache-control: no-cache
```

I have been setting the latter with the following line in my C# codebehind:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

Is there a special way to indicate both directives at once? Do I just separate them with a semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the OnInit event like this:

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"; 

            base.OnInit(e);
        }
```

Maybe a good idea to create HttpModule for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I am already doing this in the OnInit method. The question is, what is the proper way to specify multiple CacheControl directives?